# Integrate log wall into a concrete wall

Tags: building

**Note: I'm not building the house at the moment, just doing some research.**

Say, one already has a concrete foundation ready for the main part of the house and garage (both of them share one platform). House mostly is gonna be made of logs, but the garage is concrete as so the some of the walls of the house. What is the best way to integrate logs into concrete giving the fact that wood logs would push down on itself in time?

**Updated:**

On the diagram below, the places where logs run into the concrete are highlighted by red rectangles.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't completely clear what you're talking about; would you add a diagram, or some more explanation?

Comment: @Daniel Griscom Added the diagram.

Comment: That's great! I've got to assume there's a "standard" way to do this; let's see if someone here knows.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do "integrate into concrete" and *push down on itself" mean? If the logs are an interior design element, how you finish your walls is critical information.

Comment: Usually log walls are held together at the corners by notched joinery to another  wall at a right angle.  Since these are terminating against concrete wall there is no lateral support to keep the logs from sliding off one another. I would suggest that perhaps you do a traditional log wall and then the concrete wall next to the log wall.  just a guess because this is not something i have ever seen.  cast logs out of concrete?

Comment: I doubt if the logs “run into the concrete”. They probably run up to the wall and attach to the wall.